# Verificar janela popup aberto ou fechado

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas páginas, a página `teste`, e a `verifica`.
Gostaria de abrir um *popup* com o `windows.open` na página `teste.html`, e este *popup* vai se chamar `verifica.html`.

A página `verifica.html` tem que verificar se a página `teste.html` esta `closed=true` ou `false`.

Já fiz muitos códigos, más não consegui nada, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Eu tenho um codigo q faz isso. Vou procurar nos meus arquivos aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável que será atribuída ao popup:

```
var minhaPopUp;
```

Ao abrir a popup usando `window.open`, atribua o comando à variável:

```
onclick="minhaPopUp=window.open('verifica.html','verifica','width=400,height=200')"
```

E uma função que irá verificar se ela está aberta:

```
function ver_PopUp(){
        if (!minhaPopUp || minhaPopUp.closed) {
            alert('Popup fechada');
        }else{
            alert('Popup aberta');
        }
}
```

[**Teste no Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uygn95go/)

Answer (score 0):

Porque não tenta armazenar o valor em um cookie?

Assim que enviar o evento pra abrir o pop up você cria o cookie e no evento de fechar a janela você remove o cookie.

Encontrei este código pode ser útil também(Execute o código e veja como ele se comporta):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Minha página</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numero_url = 5
janela = new Array(numero_url)

function AbreJanela(url, id) {
numero = id.replace("contato","")
janela[parseInt(numero)] = window.open(url,"1_2","width=500,height=350");
// Verifica se a janela foi aberta... É só um exemplo !
VerificaJanela(id)
// Claro que vai dizer que está aberta, pois acabamos de abrir...
}
function VerificaJanela(valor) {
    numero = valor.replace("contato","")
    if (janela[numero]!=null && !janela[numero].closed) {
        alert("A janela foi aberta, mas não está fechada")
    }else if (janela[numero]!=null && janela[numero].closed) {
        alert("A janela foi aberta e já foi fechada")
    }else{
        alert("A janela ainda não foi aberta")
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="AbreJanela('pop.php?msg_remet=1&msg_usuId2=2', this.id)" id="contato1"'>Contato 1</a>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Verificar se a janela de número 1 está aberta" onclick="VerificaJanela('contato1')">
</body>
</html>
```

Fonte: https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/128757-resolvido%C2%A0verificar-se-popup-est%C3%A1-aberto/

Comment: Excelente, acho que pode resolver meu problema, vou testar e já te digo.